# Query numerical string values in Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am failing to query a string property set with a numerical value. Example:

```
//entity in orion
{
    "id": "Test.2",
    "type": "Test",
    "nombre": "1"
}

//query
http://<some-ip>:<some-port>/v2/entities?type=Test&q=nombre==1

//response
[]
```

I changed the attribute to store a number and the query works well then. Anyway, it should be possible to query numerical string values, shouldn't it?

**EDIT**

I found this [problem](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1129) will be issued in version 0.26

Comment: The issue has been provisionally associated to the 0.26.0 milestone. However note that issue-to-milestone allocation use to change (it is reviewed in a monthly basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [the issue cited by @nespapu](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1129), NGSIv2 will allow that posibility in the following way:

```
//query
http://<some-ip>:<some-port>/v2/entities?type=Test&q=nombre=='1'
```

However, current Orion version at the time of writting this (0.24.0) doesn't implemented yet such functionality.

**EDIT:** implemented since Orion 1.3.0